# difference between next_execution_date and data_interval_end on Airflow?

Tags: macros, airflow

We recently migrated to Airflow 2.3.3.

We get some warnings followed by exception saying `next_execution_date` is deprecated , so use `data_interval_end` instead.

But when we changed, we got some failures regarding the `time difference` between these 2 macros.

Also, i checked the code, both are using `UTC timezone`.